# Flutter ListView is not displaying items

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, widget

I am trying to set up a very simple `ListView` that from the top to the bottom of the screen, but right now I don't see any thing on the screen but a *green* background.

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {


List wishlists = [Wishlist("Test1"), Wishlist("Yeet")];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 400,
        child: new ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new WishlistListWidget(
              wishlist: wishlists[index],
            );
          },
          itemCount: wishlists.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`Wishlist` is a simple `Class` and this is my `WishlistListWidget`:

```
class WishlistListWidget extends StatelessWidget {


final Wishlist wishlist;
  const WishlistListWidget({Key key, this.wishlist}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 150.0,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                    bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm able to see the content. Text color of the item is white.

Comment: @TirthPatel with my exact code? Why is it not working for me?

Comment: Yes, I tried in dartpad. Instead of rendering a wishlist widget, I rendered static text. I kept the widget tree the same.

Comment: @TirthPatel tried it with text as well and it is working for me. But what is wrong with my Widget then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `Text` widget in `WishlistListWidget` class.

```dart
class WishlistListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Wishlist wishlist; // this value is not being used here
  const WishlistListWidget({Key key, this.wishlist}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 150.0,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: new Container(
              child: Text(wishlist.someProperty), // this one, it should be wishlist.someProperty
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                  bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ok I can see it now, but why do I have do use `Text` in order for it to be displayed?

Comment: Text is use to display the text. In current code, value of `wishlist` is not displayed anywhere because you've not used a text widget.

Comment: yes but what if I don't want to use `text` in my `listWidget`?

Comment: Then it won't be displayed.

Comment: You need to use Text somewhere if you want to display text.